# Java.g: ambiguous 'statement' rule? (assert)

Tags: antlr, antlr3

In [Java.g](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g), we can find the following rule (whitespace removed for clarity):

```
statement 
     :   block
         |   ('assert') expression (':' expression)? ';'
         |   'assert'  expression (':' expression)? ';'            
         |   'if' parExpression statement ('else' statement)?          
         (...)
         ;
```

I've two questions:

1. Are two 'assert' subrules really needed?
2. If not, why doesn't ANTLR complain of ambiguity, since they seem to define exactly the same input?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Pedro F. wrote:***
>
> Are two 'assert' subrules really needed?

No, they're equivalent. However, by looking at the way the grammar [Java.g](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g) is formatted:

```
statement 
    :   block

    |   ('assert'
        )
        expression (':' expression)? ';'
    |   'assert'  expression (':' expression)? ';'     
    |   ...
```

I suspect (by looking at the empty spaces) that the grammar originally had embedded code in it:

```
statement 
    :   block     { /* embedded code */
        }    
    |   ('assert' { /* embedded code */ }
        )
        expression (':' expression)? ';'
    |   'assert'  expression (':' expression)? ';'     
    |   ...
```

and that perhaps more rules/tokens were stripped (all guesswork, of course!).

> ***Pedro F. wrote:***
>
> If not, why doesn't ANTLR complain of ambiguity, since they seem to define exactly the same input?

Because global backtracking (the `backtrack=true;` in the options) is enabled.